# Select web form elements with specific attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have the following HTML form:

```
<form name="catForm">
   <select name="group">
     <option value="1">Group 1</option> 
     <option value="2">Group 2</option> 
   </select>
   <select name="catid[1]" catid="1">
     <option value="1">1</option> 
     <option value="2">2</option> 
   </select>
   <select name="catid[3]" catid="3">
     <option value="1">1</option> 
     <option value="2">2</option> 
   </select>
</form>
```

How to select using (JavaScript or jQuery) all `SELECT`'s from my form (only those having `catid` attribute) and show its `catid` attribute values and selected option values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[has attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)**:

```
$('select[catid]');
```

And then iterate over returned elements using `.each()` and log the values and attributes.

**Working Snippet:**

```js
$('select[catid]').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr("catid"));
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="catForm">
   <select name="group">
     <option value="1">Group 1</option> 
     <option value="2">Group 2</option> 
   </select>
   <select name="catid[1]" catid="1">
     <option value="1">1</option> 
     <option value="2">2</option> 
   </select>
   <select name="catid[3]" catid="3">
     <option value="1">1</option> 
     <option value="2">2</option> 
   </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter()` method passing the attribute selector as parameter:

```js
var cat = [];
$('select').filter('[name^="catid"]').each(function() {
  cat.push($(this).attr('name'));
});
alert(cat);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="catForm">
   <select name="group">
     <option value="1">Group 1</option> 
     <option value="2">Group 2</option> 
   </select>
   <select name="catid[1]" catid="1">
     <option value="1">1</option> 
     <option value="2">2</option> 
   </select>
   <select name="catid[3]" catid="3">
     <option value="1">1</option> 
     <option value="2">2</option> 
   </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('select[name^=catid]').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr("catid")); // get attribute using this
  console.log($(this).val()); // get selected value using this
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="catForm">
   <select name="group">
     <option value="1">Group 1</option> 
     <option value="2">Group 2</option> 
   </select>
   <select name="catid[1]" catid="1">
     <option value="1" selected>1</option> 
     <option value="2">2</option> 
   </select>
   <select name="catid[3]" catid="3">
     <option value="1">1</option> 
     <option value="2" selected>2</option> 
   </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it should be help to you

```
var categories= $('[catid]').serialize();
console.log(categories);
```

This will be generate name and value mapping in querystring format you can use this string in ajax method as data as a post method.

See this: https://jsfiddle.net/gredztox/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select[name^="catid"]` method for selecting an multiple array elements with its name.

```
<script>
$(document).on('change','select',function(){
  var catArr = [];
  $('select[name^="catid"]').each(function() {
    catArr.push($(this).val());
  });
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = catArr;
});
</script>
```

Your Final [Output](https://jsfiddle.net/1xd4rrth/12/)